# Как на Node.js написать программу, которая будет автоматически запускать сервер, если он упадёт?

Tags: javascript, node.js, сервер

Где-то слышал, что такое возможно. Проблема в том, что на vps сервере node.js автоматически вырубается и я не знаю, как сделать, чтобы он работал постоянно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для подобной проблемы уже есть немало готовых решений.
Среди них, например, [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2).
Просто устанавливаете как глобальный NPM-пакет:

```
sudo npm i pm2 -g
```

и в самом простом случае просто запускаете свою программу с помощью данной утилиты:

```
sudo pm2 start app.js
```